# A Borel measure with finite support

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a compact uniform space and $\mu$ be a Borel Measure. Also let $supp(\mu)$ is a finite set. Is it true that $\mu$ is a finite convex combination of Dirac measures?

Please help me to know it

Answer (score 2):

If support of $\mu$ is $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ then  $\mu = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \mu(\{x_k\}) \delta_{x_k}$. To prove this just use the fact that $\mu (E)=\mu (E \cap \{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\})$ for any Borel set $E$.